# yii redis extention include(Redis.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, yii, redis

yii-redis extention http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-redis/

```
        Yii::app()->redis->getClient()->set("myKey", "Your Value");

        echo Yii::app()->redis->getClient()->get("myKey"); // outputs "Your Value"

        Yii::app()->redis->getClient()->del("myKey"); // deletes the key
```

i get error:

include(Redis.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

From the extension page:

> This package relies on the https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis PHP extension, please make sure this is installed before continuing.

Comment: i do install phpredis and  try  set and get keys in terminal
redis-cli 

set key2 "ff"
then get key2  and its work fine

Answer (score 1):

I think you just installed `redis server` not `PHP extension for Redis`. You must install PHP extension for Redis to make your PHP code work with Redis.

You can checking by using this function `phpinfo()`. If you see `Redis` in the output info then you installed it.

To install it you can see:

- https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/issues/213#issuecomment-11361242 (used for Window).
- http://raphaelstolt.blogspot.com/2010/05/installing-php-redis-extension-on-mac.html (used for MAC).
- http://www.lecloud.net/post/3378834922/install-redis-php-extension-phpredis-with-macports

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Debian-like OS(Ubuntu, Mint, etc...), you shoud try:

```
sudo apt-get install redis-server php5-redis && sudo service apache2 restart
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: php5-redis is not a package for install